# Multiple-entry schengen visa questions

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry

based on the rules for longer term multiple entry schengen visas, which are that

"Multiple-entry visas with a long validity shall be issued for the following validity periods, unless the validity of the visa would exceed that of the travel document:

(a) for a validity period of one year, provided that the applicant has obtained and lawfully used three visas within the previous two years;"

**Does anyone know whether:**

**Do the 'lawfully used three visas' have be issued from the same country?** For example, I've had one visa from France, one from Italy, one from Spain. Would those three together count?

**Do the three visas need to be of the same type?** For example, one visa I had is just a short stay tourist visa and the other is also a short stay tourist visa but I applied on the basis that I am married to an EU citizen (I am an non-EU national).

Comment: As a spouse of an EU citizen you recieved only a single entry visa? Otherwise it doesn't matter which country issued the previous visas.

Comment: The EU spouse visa was multiple entry, but its only valid for 30 days of travel within a 90 day period

Comment: You mean 90 days in every 180 day period? This only applies when you are not travelling or joining your EU citizen spouse.

Comment: No it's the visa where we need to travel together (EU national with EU spouse).

Comment: Post covid, it seems these guidelines/rules have gone for a toss. I know numerous people who despite having 4-5 visas in the previous two years, were issued visas ranging from 10-30 days and I know one person who applied for a Schengen visa for the first time in their life (for a 15 day trip) and received a 5 years multiple entry visa.

Comment: @ThomasCruise Thank you. I'm finding it inconsistent too. Do you know which country issued that person the five year visa?

Comment: @Gussss It was Switzerland. But Switzerland also issued 30 day visas to those who had 4-5 Schengen visas in the past two years. So there is no consistency. Just apply normally as per your plans and don't expect much. If you get a longer duration visa, it's your luck.